# How can I disable html tag completion in PHPStorm

Tags: html, autocomplete, phpstorm

When I'm in HTML/Other context and type `foobar` and hit Tab it automatically turns into `<foobar></foobar>`. Is there any option to turn this kind of auto complete off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**`Settings | Emmet | XML | Enable XML Emmet`** -- disable this option.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I already guessed it has something to do with Emmet, but didn't think of XML being the "problem".