# How do I stop PhpStorm 2016.2 from entering the form tag when I type the word "form" into a paragraph?

Tags: phpstorm

After typing the word "form" and entering a space, PhpStorm makes a form! No! No! How do I get PhpStorm to stop doing that?

p.s. stackoverflow won't let me post the images because my reputation is <10 :(

UPDATE. My progress.. or lack thereof:
**I've done this without success:**

1. Settings | Emmet | XML | Enable XML Emmet -- disable this option. (as recommended in [How can I disable html tag completion in PHPStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607799/how-can-i-disable-html-tag-completion-in-phpstorm))
2. Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion | Autopopup code completion -- unchecked it (as recommended in [Turn off autocomplete in PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959553/turn-off-autocomplete-in-phpstorm))
3. Settings | Editor | General | SmartKeys | XML/HTML | Auto Close tags when typing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn off autocomplete in PhpStorm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959553/turn-off-autocomplete-in-phpstorm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable html tag completion in PHPStorm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607799/how-can-i-disable-html-tag-completion-in-phpstorm)

Comment: This sounds like Emmet to me, too. Not sure why turning that off didn't work for you.

Comment: You have a `Space` as hot key setup to expand either Emmet template .. or particular Live Template. Post screenshots with your settings (post them somewhere else and provide links to them here). ideally would be good to see some screencast as well (to see what's exactly going on on a screen when it happens).

Comment: @LazyOne -- I have screenshots, but my reputation is too low to post them. I could email them to you? Your reputation is higher and you could post them for me?